# Name for grid system

Tags: definition, recreational-mathematics, applications, integer-lattices

Is there a name for a type of grid you might find in Battleship? Where coordinates don't relate to points on a grid but rather the squares themselves?

Comment: Surely you can just make a rule to say that the bottom-left integer coordinate represents the square you want and you are done!

Comment: I don't really see this as a _Mathematics_ question. But maybe you want an "array"?

Comment: No I am asking about the name/definition of such a coordinate system within a mathematical framework. For instance we normally deal with Cartesian coordinate systems but I am wondering if there is a name for the variant mentioned in the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Grid" is as good a name as any: See [Regular Grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid) in Wikipedia: In particular, see the "related" grid: the Cartesian Grid:

> "A Cartesian grid is a special case where the **elements are unit squares or unit cubes** [cubes in the case of a 3-D grid], and the vertices are integer points." [brackets, bold-face mine].

You could also refer to this sort of "playing field" in a game like battleship as an **[incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix)** of sorts: where a cell in the ith row and jth column might be occupied, using "$1$", or not occupied, using "$0$".

Comment: I must be forming some sort of dyslexia! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about [alpha-numeric grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-numeric_grid)?  That the coordinates refer to squares rather than vertices is no big deal.  Squares can be identified with vertices in the [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) of the square lattice (which is also a square lattice).

Answer (score 0):

*Cell-centered grid* may be a slightly better name, for when the coordinates refer to the cell. By contrast in a *node-centered grid*, the coordinates refer to the points on the grid.

The distinction is important in applications such as [digital image processing](https://au.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html), [computational fluid dynamics](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110002899.pdf) and data sets for [topography and bathymetry](https://ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/gridregistration.html).